# Celluloid::Notifications Failing After App Daemonized

Tags: ruby, celluloid

I'm using Celluloid::Notifications publish/subscribe to communicate between two actors. Everything works fine when running the app normally but when I try and run it in the background the subscribing actor fails to receive the notification. I've tried a number of different gems for daemonizing all of which seem to break the notifications.

The app does work when run with nohup which leads me to believe the issue has to do with the forking that's part of the daemonization process.

Comment: I'd be glad to look into this. Do you have a gist up somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

## You need to `fork` *before* you instantiate actors.

Demonizing is no problem using `command &` and having the `Process.pid` stored... but if you want to truly `fork`, you need to `fork` before the actor system goes online... which itself instantiates actors, including the ones handling notifications ( as you noticed ).